# Convert attributes to elements

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

Hello I have the following XML,

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<root>
<document> 
    <field   level = "document" name = "Client Number" value = "00000300688"/>
    <field   level = "document" name = "Client Short Name" value = "SOME CLIENT"/>
    <field   level = "document" name = "IBS Oper Acct ACBS Cust Num" value = "00004437252"/>
    <field   level = "document" name = "Document Type" value = "LaserPro Disbursement Request form"/>
    <field   level = "document" name = "Effective Date" value = "02-13-2014"/>
</document> 
</root>
```

I'd need to format it like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<root>
<document>
    <ClientNumber>00000300688</ClientNumber>
    <ClientShortName>SOME CLIENT</ClientShortName>
    <IBSOperAcctACBSCustNum>00004437252</IBSOperAcctACBSCustNum>
    <DocumentType>LaserPro Disbursement Request form</DocumentType>
    <EffectiveDate>02-13-2014</EffectiveDate>
</document> 
</root>
```

So, basically I need to convert my attributes to elements (removing the spaces of course as I think elements cannot contain spaces).

The catch to this is I have over 30,000 XML files I need to convert like this. I'm then using SSIS to import this data into a table in SQL server. Basically each one of my .xml files is a single row in the destination table. I want my XML attributes to become the columns in that table and the values of the attribute to be the row data.

I'm very new to XML so any tips are a help! Thanks so much!

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. I need help with how to bulk transform the 30,000+ xml files from the source formatting (attributes) to the desired output (elements). That make sense? Sorry if I'm being confusing!

Comment: Also, if there is some way to accomplish this via a .xsd file in SSIS that would be ideal. I know how to do a foreachloop in SSIS which will handle going through the 30,000+ files.

Comment: Is this a one-time data migration, or do you have to do this periodically?

Comment: Periodically, but not all that often. Probably quarterly. So it doesn't have to be fully automated or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT transform:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(@name, ' ', '')}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will take your given XML:**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<root>
<document> 
    <field   level = "document" name = "Client Number" value = "00000300688"/>
    <field   level = "document" name = "Client Short Name" value = "SOME CLIENT"/>
    <field   level = "document" name = "IBS Oper Acct ACBS Cust Num" value = "00004437252"/>
    <field   level = "document" name = "Document Type" value = "LaserPro Disbursement Request form"/>
    <field   level = "document" name = "Effective Date" value = "02-13-2014"/>
</document> 
</root>
```

**And yield the following XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <document> 
      <ClientNumber>00000300688</ClientNumber>
      <ClientShortName>SOME CLIENT</ClientShortName>
      <IBSOperAcctACBSCustNum>00004437252</IBSOperAcctACBSCustNum>
      <DocumentType>LaserPro Disbursement Request form</DocumentType>
      <EffectiveDate>02-13-2014</EffectiveDate>
   </document> 
</root>
```

**As requested.**

Comment: Thank you!!! Using the XSLD above I created an XML Task in SSIS Control Flow. The XML Task loops through and opens each of the XML files and processes it through your XSLD which generates the exact output I was looking for! I then store that output XML in a variable which gets passed into the Data Flow Task. In my Data Flow Task I have the mapping to my SQL Server table. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!!!